# How control ads in google adsense (other than blocking) and what alternatives do you suggest?

Tags: ads, adsense

I really like google adsense program , but their blocking-filter is not enough for me. I need to allow sites before they appear on my site (like what adbrite.com do)

Are their any other sites meet my criteria?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Info links is an in-text advertising network, loads a bit faster than kontera and pays a lot more.

http://adsensealternativesblog.com